# How to write a function that does not throw a "wrong number of arguments" error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a minimal function that can be called with a variable number of arguments but that will not throw a wrong number of arguments error if miscalled.

Here is where I start from :

```
function varargout=fname(varargin)
% FNAME
% Usage: output=fname(input)

% Arguments check
if(nargin~=1 || nargout~=1)
    disp('Function fname requires one input argument');
    disp('and one output argument');
    disp('Try `help fname`');
    varargout(1:nargout)={0};
    return;
end

input=varargin{1};

output=input;

varargout(1)={output};
end
```

However this does not work as I would like it to. Is there a way to write a function that :

- never throw a "wrong number of arguments" error (so that the rest of the execution can continue)
- accepts variable number of input and output arguments and checks them inside the function
- (maybe more tricky) if the number of input / output arguments is not correct, does not replace the value of the provided output arguments (so that any misplaced call does not erase the previous value of the output argument)

I am open to any suggestions / other methods.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:** thanks to @Amro for his answer, I guess what I miss here is either a call by address of reference for Matlab functions or a way to interrupt a function without returning anything and without stopping the rest of the execution.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to implement your function:

```
function varargout = fname(input,varargin)
    %# FNAME
    %# Usage: output=fname(input)

    %%# INPUT
    if nargin<1
        varargout(1:nargout) = {[]};
        warning('Not enough input arguments.'), return
    end
    if ~isempty(varargin)
        warning('Too many input arguments.')
    end

    %%# YOUR CODE: manipulate input, and compute output
    output = input;

    %%# OUTPUT
    varargout{1} = output;
    if nargout>1
        warning('Too many output arguments.')
        varargout(2:nargout) = {[]};
    end
end
```

Obviously you can customize the warning messages to your liking...

Also, if you want your function to simply print the message instead of issuing warnings, replace all [WARNING](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/warning.html) calls with simple [DISP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/disp.html) function calls.

#### Examples of function call:

```
fname()
fname(1)
fname(1,2)
x = fname()
x = fname(1)
x = fname(1,2)
[x,y] = fname()
[x,y] = fname(1)
[x,y] = fname(1,2)
```

The above calls execute as expected (showing warning messages when applicable). One caveat though, in the last three calls, if the variable `y` already existed in the workspace prior to the calls, it would be overwritten by the empty value `y=[]` in each...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is no. If a caller calls a function like this:

```
[a, b, c] = fname('foo');
```

then `fname` is required to return (at least) three outputs. There's no way to tell MATLAB that it should leave `b` and `c` alone if `fname` only returns one output.